# Is it appropriate to omit some part of a sentence in scholarly writing like this?

Tags: writing-style

> It is tempting to suppose that the traditional mountaineer had a civilizing sense of proportion that is lost on his modern counterparts. Tempting, but perilous, I think. **Less perilous,I hope, to suggest that a sense of proportion is characteristic of the best mountaineer of every epoch.**(Is mountaineering a sport? in Philosophy and Sport, ed. by Anthony O'Hear)

The last sentence in this paragraph, obviously, is not a complete sentence, is it appropriate to omit some part of s sentence in scholarly writing like this?

Answer (score 3):

Does it convey the writer's meaning in the way the writer intends? I would say that it does, particularly as it matches the previous sentence.

Comment: I think it does that and more - it reinforces the *I think*, and *I hope* in making it explicit that this is the author's opinion.

Comment: Gratuitous as my comment may appear to be, I suggest the word "is" could be inserted between "hope," and "to" without doing any irreparable damage or causing a welter of confusion.  I'm just sayin' . . ..